# Replace string with dynamic value in a line using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a file basically it is response in json but I can treat it as line of string in file. There is some value of a key that I need to replace with a dynamic value like e.g take value, do some calculation and replace with that calculated value.

For example (date change with +1):

`"dateFrom":"Jun 24, 2018 10:00:34 AM"` to `"dateFrom":"Jun 25, 2018 10:00:34 AM"`

sample string is :

```
line = {"Num":"ML3","dateFrom":"Jun 24, 2018 10:00:34 AM","Val":"mean to","dateTo":"Jun 27, 2018 10:00:34 AM","requestInfo":{"requestIdentifier":"7cecc67d"}}
```

I tried to solve this by using regular expression as below ("TEST") is dummy value but I have to take `date` and replace with `date+1`:

```
lt = re.sub(r'dateFrom|dateTo.*":(.*AM|PM)(.*)",',"TEST", line, re.IGNORECASE)
```

ultimately it did not get correct out put.

Expected:

```
line = {"Num":"ML3","dateFrom":"Jun 25, 2018 10:00:34 AM","Val":"mean to","dateTo":"Jun 28, 2018 10:00:34 AM","requestInfo":{"requestIdentifier":"7cecc67d"}}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Sample data is :
`{"lAttributes":[{"Identifier":{"newIdentifier":{"DDline":"BM","guideIdDate":"Jun 25, 2018 12:00:00 AM","guideNo":"MM","suffix":"A"},"origin":"FRY","destination":"DZ"},"guideOwner":"VX","guideRegistration":"DD","guideType":"44","bestDepartureStatus":"S","bestArrivalTime":"Jun 25, 2018 6:00:00 AM","bestArrivalStatus":"S","bestDepartureTime":"Jun 25, 2018 5:00:00 AM","compartments":[{"code":"DD","guideCapacity":8,"guideBooked":0,"guideForecast":0},{"code":"DD","guideCapacity":10,"guideBooked":0,"guideForecast":0},{"code":"DD","guideCapacity":32,"guideBooked":0,"guideForecast":0},{"code":"DD","guideCapacity":24,"guideBooked":0,"guideForecast":0}]}]}`

Comment: First of all, not `re.IGNORECASE` but `flags=re.IGNORECASE`. Why not use `json`?

Comment: I tried with json but got in to trouble while replacing nested level of key:value, so i thought of using regx would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign a value to the dictionary key like so:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

line = {"Num":"ML3","dateFrom":"Jun 24, 2018 10:00:34 AM","Val":"mean to","dateTo":"Jun 27, 2018 10:00:34 AM","requestInfo":{"requestIdentifier":"7cecc67d"}}

# Adds 1 day to dateFrom
new_date = datetime.strptime(line["dateFrom"], '%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p') + timedelta(days=1)

# Formats new date as a string and assigns it to dictionary key
line["dateFrom"] = datetime.strftime(new_date, '%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

```
print(line)
>>>{'Num': 'ML3', 'dateFrom': 'Jun 25, 2018 10:00:34 AM', 'Val': 'mean to', 'dateTo': 'Jun 27, 2018 10:00:34 AM', 'requestInfo': {'requestIdentifier': '7cecc67d'}}
```

---

If you need to convert a json string representation to a dictionary (this is a little unclear in your question), you can use the `json` library:

```
import json

line = '{"Num":"ML3","dateFrom":"Jun 24, 2018 10:00:34 AM","Val":"mean to","dateTo":"Jun 27, 2018 10:00:34 AM","requestInfo":{"requestIdentifier":"7cecc67d"}}'

line = json.loads(line)
```

Comment: Thanks, If we have one layered json then we can  but i have nested json. In that case how i could get path of that key to change. I can iterate over nested json but finding difficult to replace that. Any suggestion?

Comment: @BimleshSharma Can you add a 'nested' example to your question? It's a little unclear to me what you mean. You should just be able to sub reference it e.g. `json_1["json_2"]["dateFrom"]`

Comment: we have to replace all date fields. I know it comes at fixed place but json is too long and we cant reference manually.  I have added sample in question. Please refer.

Comment: @BimleshSharma based on your example, you would need to loop over all of the relevant keys. It _looks_ like a valid way of determining them would be all keys whose name ends in `Date` or `Time`.

Comment: Finding key and value is not an issue. After finding replacing those value with dynamically changed value is an issue. i can use regular expression but that not sure how i can replace all occurrence of key's value in that line.